# Data comparison query, how to omptimize it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing a comparison between 2 tables in Postgresql looking for differences row by row to save it in another table, but I want to know if there is another way to do it or how I can optimize it:

```
insert into changes
select 
daily2.id_registro 
from daily2 
inner join 
daily on daily2.id_registro = daily.id_registro
where
daily2.fecha_ingreso!=daily.fecha_ingreso
or
daily2.fecha_sintomas!=daily.fecha_sintomas
or
daily2.fecha_def!=daily.fecha_def
or
daily2.intubado!=daily.intubado
or
daily2.neumonia!=daily.neumonia
or
daily2.diabetes!=daily.diabetes
or
daily2.epoc!=daily.epoc
or
daily2.asma!=daily.asma
or
daily2.inmusupr!=daily.inmusupr
or
daily2.hipertension!=daily.hipertension
or
daily2.otra_com!=daily.otra_com
or
daily2.cardiovascular!=daily.cardiovascular
or
daily2.obesidad!=daily.obesidad
or
daily2.renal_cronica!=daily.renal_cronica
or
daily2.tabaquismo!=daily.tabaquismo
or
daily2.otro_caso!=daily.otro_caso
or
daily2.resultado!=daily.resultado
```

Comment: There is not much to optimize, but if both tables have exactly the same columns you can at least simplify it: `where
daily2 is distinct from daily;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that every id has a match, you can just:

```
insert into changes
select id_registro from 
(
    select * from daily2 
    except
    select * from daily
) as a
```

In this way you dont need to write each column.

If you need to be sure that id is in both table you can just add a check to see if id is in both tables:

```
insert into changes
select id_registro from 
(
    select * from daily2 
    except
    select * from daily
) as a
where a.id_registro in
(
    select daily2.id_registro
    from daily inner join daily2
    on daily.id_registro = daily2.id_registro 
);
```

This is pretty heavy, so be careful on giant tables.

Answer (score 1):

Do you  want tuple (in)equality?

```
where
    (daily2.fecha_ingreso, daily2.fecha_sintomas, daily2.fecha_def, ...) 
    <> (daily.fecha_ingreso, daily.fecha_sintomas, daily.fecha_def, ...)
```

I wonder whether that the whole query would be more efficiently phrased with `exists`:

```
insert into changes (id_registro)
select d2.id_registro 
from daily2 d2
where exists (
    select 1
    from daily d
    where 
        d1.id_registro = d.id_registro
        and (d2.fecha_ingreso, d2.fecha_sintomas, d2.fecha_def, ...) 
         <> (d.fecha_ingreso, d.fecha_sintomas, d.fecha_def, ...)
)
```

Comment: thank you is another way to do it. it is the best choice?

Comment: @CarlosEspinozaGarcia: I think a `join` or `exists` is more efficient that the other solution using `except`, which requires multiple table scans. I like `exists`, but you would have to check how it compares to your `join` solution in terms of efficient.

Comment: i appreciate your comments